# How to iterate through a list of different objects?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, abstract-class

*note: I'm under an NDA so I have to use variable names that dont make sense. Sorry*

Hello!
I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class A {

    public abstract List<String> someMethod();

}
```

and two classes that extend that abstract class:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@XmlRootElement(name = "BField")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class B extends A {
...
}

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@XmlRootElement(name = "CField")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class C extends A {
...
}
```

Then somewhere in the code there is a class that makes a list of those two classes. Pretty much looks like this:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "MyStuffData")
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    @XmlElementRefs({
            @XmlElementRef(name = "B", type = B.class),
            @XmlElementRef(name = "C", type = C.class),
    })
    private List<A> myStuff;
```

The contents of `myStuff` can either be B or C right? How do I iterate through that list? I am getting the data from a soap request, so I'm just really confused on how to do this. I tried:

```
for(A a: myStuff){
       ...some code here...
}
```

However I am getting this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to some.package.here.A
```

I heard lax=true can solve the problem, but I still get the same error. What's puzzling is that I can get the size of the list which is pretty accurate but then I cant iterate through it. Any help would be appreciated. **sorry I'm not that good at explaining so finding this kind of stuff on google is kinda of a pain.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this use case you should not use `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)`.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/12/jaxbs-xmlanyelementlaxtrue-explained.html

---

**USE CASE #1 - @XmlElementRef**

When using `@XmlElementRef` you need to ensure that the element name on the `@XmlElementRef` annotation matches the `@XmlRootElement` (or `@XmlElementDecl`) annotation exactly.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <MyStuffData>
        <BField/>
        <CField/>
        <BField/>
    </MyStuffData>
</root>
```

**Root**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "MyStuffData")
    @XmlElementRefs({
            @XmlElementRef(name = "BField", type = B.class),
            @XmlElementRef(name = "CField", type = C.class),
    })
    private List<A> myStuff;

    public List<A> getMyStuff() {
        return myStuff;
    }

}
```

---

**USE CASE #2 - @XmlElements**

If you do not wish to have the element name the same as the root element name for the reference type you can use the `@XmlElements` annotation.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-xsd-choice-xmlelements.html

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <MyStuffData>
        <B/>
        <C/>
        <B/>
    </MyStuffData>
</root>
```

**Root**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "MyStuffData")
    @XmlElements({
            @XmlElement(name = "B", type = B.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "C", type = C.class),
    })
    private List<A> myStuff;

    public List<A> getMyStuff() {
        return myStuff;
    }

}
```

---

**COMMON**

The following are common to both use cases.

**A**

```
public abstract class A {
}
```

**B**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "BField")
public class B extends A {
}
```

**C**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "CField")
public class C extends A {
}
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum17061559/input.xml");
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        for(A a : root.getMyStuff()) {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
forum17061559.B@6998e5d9
forum17061559.C@351a3fb8
forum17061559.B@4e4d6
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `myStuff` is actually isn't `List<A>` (or `List<B>`) but, `List<ElementNSImpl>`, where `org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl` instance seems to be some kind of wrapper over actual instance of `B` or `C`.

You can debug that list and try to see if you can get `B`/`C` from `org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl`

Comment: What's puzzling is that I can get the size of the list which is pretty accurate but then I cant iterate through it. This means that the list was formed as List<A>.. ಠ_ಠ Or maybe that's just how wrappers work (I have no prior experience of jaxb and I cannot contact the person who set this up because of time zone difference atm. He is asleep, I bet). Anyhow, thanks. Will definitely try it.

Comment: @joannaSmith12 i understand , onsite off shore teams :(